# What's the difference between charge density wave and charge ordering for superconductors

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, strong-correlated

So far, my understanding is that they are the same. Charge ordering is a phase transition and the material will have charge density waves once it's in a charge ordered state...? This sounds too simple though... And a similar question would be the difference between SDW and spin ordering? Thank you!

Comment: Spin order is probably a broader notion than just SDW. It typically means that the spin rotational symmetry is broken, but it does not have to be SDW.

Comment: I think in the context of cuprate high-Tc superconductor, the charge ordering is just charge density wave (e.g. checkerboard charge density pattern).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Meng Cheng, charge ordering is a broader notion than CDW. My understanding is that CDW means charge ordering with a non-zero value for the wavevector $q$ : if your order parameter is some $\Phi(q)$, you develop a nonzero expectation value for $<\Phi(q)>$ with $q \neq 0$.

On the other hand, you could also get charge ordering for $q=0$ : it will be a uniform order, so I guess you can't call it a wave in this case.

Comment: So ferromagnetism is spin-ordered but shouldn't be called spin density wave, right? And what about AFM?

Comment: Yes, ferromagnetism would be a SDW with $q=0$, so I guess it is just a matter of terminology. And AFM is SDW, depending on the order it can be stripe-like ($(0,\pi)$ or $(\pi,0)$) ordering wavevector) or Néel-like $(\pi,\pi)$. In neutron scattering experiments you would see a peak at these wavevectors.

Comment: Could a Mott insulator be an thought of as an example of a $q=0$ charge ordered phase?